# What command to use to check whether MySQL service is available on a Mac server?

Tags: mysql, mac-osx-server, service

What command to use to check whether the MySQL service is available on a Mac OS X server?

Googled it but I couldn't find any answers.

Comment: I think, you can use same commands as in GNU/Linux (for example, it described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-out-if-mysql-is-running-on-linux/)).

Comment: I've tried using that one. It says command not found. But I don't know if it is installed because even if it is installed the command might not be in the PATH. I wonder if there is a service checking command on mac to reveal that information.

Comment: Well, you may then check the mysql process existense (`ps aux | grep mysql`) or that mysql server listens its port (`netstat -ntpl | grep 3306`).

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/macosx-installation.html